The fzf trigger ** doesn't work in the zsh shell
I'm using the zsh shell and when I type nvim ** I expect to see fzf triggered but instead I see nvim opening either the first available file in the current directory or the first directory in netrw.
Here is my zshrc configuration.
I've tried using export FZF_COMPLETION_TRIGGER='~~' to see if changing the trigger itself would help but it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: To be clear I get this same behaviour even if my ~/.zshrc file contains literally nothing other than the hashbang for the zsh binary. So I imagine that fzf isn't setting up that ** trigger at all and ** is just the zsh shell's globbing behaviour kicking in.

Please try to construct a minimal example, where your problem occurs instead of just linking your complete .zshrc. Therein you are sourcing some files (~/.fzf.zsh) whose content stay a mystery.
